# Why is it possible to mix python indentation

Tags: python, indentation

I could not believe, but it is possible to mix tabs and spaces in python code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for a in range(3): # indented with 4 spaces
        print(a)       # indented with 4 spaces and one tab
```

What is the reason behind this?

Tested on:

- Python 3.3.0 (CPython)
- Python 2.7.3 (CPython)

NOTE: It seems that stackoverflow changes tabs with spaces!

Comment: If you don't like it, use `-tt` command line switch. http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t

Comment: -tt doesnt seem to work for me :/

Comment: It only prevents inconsistent use of spaces and tabs, not all mixing of the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of many myths about Python indentation.

What Python actually does, is look at relative indentation between lines, rather than fixed amounts.

- When indentation increases between lines, it considers it the start of a block and pushes the new indentation level on a stack.
- When indentation decreases, it pops the indentation level stack until it finds a matching level, closing a block for each pop

It doesn't care whether you are using tabs, spaces, or a mixture, as long as you are consistent for each level within the scope of a block.

E.g. The following is a valid file (using [ ] to represent a space, and [t] to represent a tab)

```
if True:
[ ][ ][ ][ ]print ("Four spaces")

if True:
[t]print ("Tab")
[t]if True:
[t][ ][ ][ ]print ("Tab and three spaces")

if True:
[ ][t][ ]print ("Mixture")
```

Having said all that - most sane people stick to 4 spaces as the standard indent, the way the [Benevolent Dictator intended it](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

See [Python: Myths about Indentation](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation was introduced in python to make sure every written code has indent so that other coders can read it properly.

That doesn't mean, the coders has his freedom. As long as each block maintains its indent, different blocks can have different indent.

For example, you can have a working file like this, but NOT recommended.

```
print "hello"
if True:
[TAB]print "a"
[TAB]i = 0
[TAB]if i == 0:
[TAB][SPACE][SPACE]print "b"
[TAB][SPACE][SPACE]j = i + 1
[TAB][SPACE][SPACE]if j == 1:
[TAB][SPACE][SPACE][TAB][TAB]print "c
```

More read... http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html